# When does curl of a surface integral vanish?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-spaces

Suppose $V\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be non-empty and at least twice differentiable (Smooth) and let $S$ be the surface that encloses $V$ (for example a sphere). Let $\textbf{F}\in \mathbb{R}^3$ be a smooth vector field for all space. Let $\textbf{n}$ denote the normal to the surface $S$. For what conditions do we have $$\textbf{curl}\biggl(\oint_{S}^{}{\textbf{n}\times\dfrac{\textbf{F}(\textbf{r}^\prime)}{|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}^\prime|} ~ds}\biggr) = \textbf{0}$$ Is this even possible?

Naturally, I want to commute the curl $$\textbf{curl}\biggl(\oint_{S}^{}{\textbf{n}\times\dfrac{\textbf{F}(\textbf{r}^\prime)}{|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}^\prime|} ~ds}\biggr) 
 = \oint_{S}^{}{ \textbf{curl}\biggl(\textbf{n}\times\dfrac{\textbf{F}(\textbf{r}^\prime)}{|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}^\prime|} \biggr) ~ds} $$ and use the cross-product identity $$\textbf{Curl}(\textbf{A}\times \textbf{B}) = \textbf{B} ~\textbf{Div}(\textbf{A}) - \textbf{A} ~\textbf{Div}(\textbf{B})  + (\textbf{A} \cdot \nabla)\textbf{B}- (\textbf{B}\cdot \nabla )\textbf{A}   $$ to deduce something on $\textbf{F}.$ What can we say about this field $\textbf{F}$. Is this a special vector field or is this impossible.

Comment: Presumably you want $\mathbf{F}$ to be nonzero... ;)

Comment: @neal trivially